# Buscador con sentencia LIKE en SQLite, con Python y la libreria Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, tkinter, sqlite3, like

estoy desarrollando un proyecto, y al momento de agregar un buscador,
no me funciona correctamente, tipeo algo en el mismo y me arroja el siguiente error

sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied.
The current statement uses 0, and there are X supplied.

tengo declarada la funcion de busqueda, y esta asignada al boton de buscar, si cambio algo en la consulta se queda en blanco sin arrojar ningun resultado aparente,
pareciera que queda buscando luego de clickar en el boton buscar y nunca llega a mostrarme lo que indique en el cuadro de busqueda. sinceramente ya agote todos mis conocimientos y me quede estancado en este paso.
agradeceria mucho la ayuda y si pueden explicarme correctamente donde estaba fallando para poder avanzar.

les comparto mi codigo.

saludos.

la lineas de comentario debajo de la funcion de busqueda son las otras opciones que intente.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import csv
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3



class Stock:
 # propiedades de la conexion a base de datos---
db_name = 'database.db'

def __init__(self, window):

    # Inicializacion 
    self.Ventana_Principal = window
    self.Ventana_Principal.title('Software Prueba')

    # Contenedor de Entrada de datos
    frame = LabelFrame(self.Ventana_Principal, text = 'Productos--')
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 30, padx = 30, pady = 30)

    # Entrada de Clave
    Label(frame, text = 'Clave: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    self.Clave = Entry(frame)
    self.Clave.focus()
    self.Clave.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    # Entrada de Unidad
    Label(frame, text = 'Unidad: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    self.Unidad = Entry(frame)
    self.Unidad.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    # Entrada de Nombre Producto
    Label(frame, text = 'Nombre: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    self.Nombre = Entry(frame)
    self.Nombre.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    # Entrada de Cantidad
    Label(frame, text = 'Cantidad: ').grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    self.Cantidad = Entry(frame)
    self.Cantidad.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

    # Entrada de Precio Compra
    Label(frame, text = 'Precio Compra: ').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    self.PrecioCompra = Entry(frame)
    self.PrecioCompra.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

    # Entrada de Precio Venta
    Label(frame, text = 'Precio Venta: ').grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    self.PrecioVenta = Entry(frame)
    self.PrecioVenta.grid(row = 3, column = 3)


    # Boton Agregar Producto - Importar Archivo
    ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Guardar Producto', command = self.agregar_productos).grid(row = 10, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E)
    

    #Seccion de Busqueda
    Label(frame, text = 'Buscar: ').grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    self.Buscador = Entry(frame, textvariable = StringVar())
    self.Buscador.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    Button(frame, text = "Buscar Producto", command = self.buscar_registro).grid(row = 4, column = 2)
    

    # Mensajes de Salida 
    self.mensaje = Label(text = '', fg = 'red')
    self.mensaje.grid(row = 3, column = 5, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E)

    # Tabla
    self.tabla = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = ('#1','#2','#3','#4'))
    self.tabla.grid(row = 4, column = 5, columnspan = 5)
    self.tabla.heading('#0', text = 'Codigo/Clave', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tabla.heading('#1', text = 'Producto', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tabla.heading('#2', text = 'Cantidad', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tabla.heading('#3', text = 'Precio Compra', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tabla.heading('#4', text = 'Precio Venta', anchor = CENTER)
   
    # Botones Eliminar - Editar - Importar 
    ttk.Button(text = 'Editar', command = self.editar_productos).grid(row = 5, column = 5, sticky = W + E)
    ttk.Button(text = 'Eliminar', command = self.eliminar_productos).grid(row = 5, column = 9, sticky = W + E)
    ttk.Button(text = 'Importar Archivo', command = self.importar_csv).grid(row = 1, column = 7, sticky = W + E)
    ttk.Button(text = 'Exportar Archivo', command = self.exportar_csv).grid(row = 2, column = 7, sticky = W + E)
    
    # Ordenando las filas
    self.ordenar_productos()

# Funcion a ejecutar en la base de datos --Querys--
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result

# Leer Tabla de base de datos
def ordenar_productos(self):
    # Limpiar Tabla 
    records = self.tabla.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tabla.delete(element)
    # Seleccionar datos
    query = 'SELECT * FROM Productos ORDER BY Clave DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    # Acomodar datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tabla.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = row[3:7])


def buscar_registro(self):
    self.buscar = self.Buscador.get()
    query = "SELECT Nombre FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%"+self.buscar+"%' ORDER BY Nombre DESC"   #"SELECT Nombre FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%"+self.Buscador.get()+"%' ORDER BY Nombre DESC"
    parameters = (self.buscar)   
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
    self.ordenar_productos()
    
    #palabra = self.Buscador.get()
    #query = "SELECT Nombre FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%"+self.buscar+"%' ORDER BY Nombre DESC"
    #parameters = (self.buscar)   
    #self.run_query(query, parameters).fetchall()
    #self.ordenar_productos()



# Validacion de datos ingresados por el usuario
def validacion(self):
    return len(self.Clave.get()) != 0 and len(self.Nombre.get()) != 0 and len(self.Cantidad.get()) != 0 and len(self.PrecioCompra.get()) != 0 and len(self.PrecioVenta.get()) != 0

# Funcion Agregar Productos
def agregar_productos(self):
    if self.validacion():
        query = 'INSERT INTO Productos VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
        parameters =  (self.Clave.get(), self.Unidad.get(), self.Nombre.get(), self.Cantidad.get(), self.PrecioCompra.get(), self.PrecioVenta.get())
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Producto {} Se Agrego Correctamente'.format(self.Nombre.get())
        self.Clave.delete(0, END)
        self.Unidad.delete(0, END)
        self.Nombre.delete(0, END)
        self.Cantidad.delete(0, END)
        self.PrecioCompra.delete(0, END)
        self.PrecioVenta.delete(0, END)
    else:
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Los Campos no Pueden estar Vacios'
    self.ordenar_productos()
    
# Funcion de Eliminar
def eliminar_productos(self):
    self.mensaje['text'] = ''
    try:
       self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Debe Seleccionar un Registro'
        return
    self.mensaje['text'] = ''
    nombre = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['text']
    query = 'DELETE FROM Productos WHERE Clave = ?'
    self.run_query(query, (nombre, ))
    self.mensaje['text'] = 'Registro {} Eliminado'.format(nombre)
    self.ordenar_productos()


# Funcion de Edicion
def editar_productos(self):
    self.mensaje['text'] = ''
    try:
        self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Debe Seleccionar un Registro'
        return
    Nombre_Anterior = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][0]
    Cantidad_Anterior = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][1]
    Precio_Anterior_Compra = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][2]
    Precio_Anterior_Venta = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][3]
    self.Ventana_Edicion = Toplevel()
    self.Ventana_Edicion.title ('Editar Producto')
    
    # Nombre Anterior
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nombre Anterior:').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion, textvariable = StringVar(self.Ventana_Edicion, value = Nombre_Anterior), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 0, column = 2)
    
    # Nuevo Nombre
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nuevo Nombre:').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    Nuevo_Nombre = Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion)
    Nuevo_Nombre.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

     # Cantidad Anterior 
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Stock Anterior:').grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion, textvariable = StringVar(self.Ventana_Edicion, value = Cantidad_Anterior), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    
    # Nueva Cantidad
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nuevo Stock:').grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    Nueva_Cantidad= Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion)
    Nueva_Cantidad.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

    # Precio Compra Anterior
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Precio Compra Anterior :').grid(row = 0, column = 3)
    Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion, textvariable = StringVar(self.Ventana_Edicion, value = Precio_Anterior_Compra), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 0, column = 4)
    
    # Nuevo Precio de Compra
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nuevo Precio Compra:').grid(row = 1, column = 3)
    Nuevo_Precio_Compra= Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion)
    Nuevo_Precio_Compra.grid(row = 1, column = 4)

    # Precio Venta Anterior 
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Precio Venta Anterior:').grid(row = 2, column = 3)
    Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion, textvariable = StringVar(self.Ventana_Edicion, value = Precio_Anterior_Venta), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 2, column = 4)
    
    # Nuevo Precio de Venta
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nuevo Precio Venta:').grid(row = 3, column = 3)
    Nuevo_Precio_Venta= Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion)
    Nuevo_Precio_Venta.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

    # Boton Actualizar
    Button(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Actualizar', command = lambda: self.editar_registros(Nuevo_Nombre.get(), Nombre_Anterior, Nueva_Cantidad.get(), Cantidad_Anterior, Nuevo_Precio_Compra.get(), Precio_Anterior_Compra, Nuevo_Precio_Venta.get(), Precio_Anterior_Venta)).grid(row = 8, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E)
    self.Ventana_Edicion.mainloop()

# funcion de edicion
def editar_registros(self, Nuevo_Nombre, Nombre_Anterior, Nueva_Cantidad, Cantidad_Anterior, Nuevo_Precio_Compra, Precio_Anterior_Compra, Nuevo_Precio_Venta, Precio_Anterior_Venta):
    query = 'UPDATE Productos SET Nombre = ?, Cantidad = ?, PrecioCompra = ?, PrecioVenta = ? WHERE Nombre = ? AND Cantidad = ? AND PrecioCompra = ? AND PrecioVenta = ?'  
    parameters = (Nuevo_Nombre, Nueva_Cantidad, Nuevo_Precio_Compra, Nuevo_Precio_Venta, Nombre_Anterior, Cantidad_Anterior, Precio_Anterior_Compra, Precio_Anterior_Venta)
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
    self.Ventana_Edicion.destroy()
    self.mensaje['text'] = 'Registro {} fue Actualizado Correctamente'.format(Nuevo_Nombre)
    self.ordenar_productos()



if __name__ == '__main__':
window = Tk()
application = Stock(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: No encuentro (a la vista y con una mini prueba) ningún error que haga lo que dices. Quizá la consulta se está tardando demasiado. Cuantas filas tiene tu tabla productos?

Comment: Por cierto, te quedó bonita la interfaz!

Comment: Hola Dante, muchas gracias! la verdad no tengo idea que pasa estoy hace varios dias con lo mismo, la tabla tiene  7 columnas de las cuales 6 son datos ingresados por el usuario y una contiene el numero identificador.

Comment: De nada c: No te preguntaba por el numero de columnas, si no por el de filas. Pero gracias igual por darme esa información.

Comment: tenes razon, perdon, lo lei rapido, actualmente tiene 146 registros, trabajaria con 200 filas aproximadamente

Comment: No pasa nada c: Que raro, no creo que 200 registros sea tanto para sqlite. Probaste el código de la pregunta a ver si ocurre el mismo error que en tu código original?

Answer (score 0):

No sé si ya lo hiciste, pero tal vez ayude a ti o a alguien más,

```
query = f"SELECT Nombre FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%{self.buscar}%' ORDER BY Nombre DESC"
```

con esta forma todas las variables que quieras poner ahí dentro del texto query las pones dentro de {} y listo

de esa forma realmente no necesitas pasarle la variable parameters.

```
def buscar_registro(self):
    self.buscar = self.Buscador.get()
    query = f"SELECT Nombre FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%{self.buscar}%' ORDER BY Nombre DESC"
    #parameters = (self.buscar)   
    self.run_query(query)
    self.ordenar_productos()
```

Comment: Hola, antes que nada gracias por tomarte tu tiempo y responder, lamento decirte que no funciono, ya lo habia probado, olvide mencionarlo en la pregunta. Ese proyecto lo deje a medias y me puse a realizar otras tareas. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

si a alguien le sirve, luego de probar y probar, mas la respuesta de arriba, he logrado hacerlo funcionar, les comparto el fragmento de la funcion buscar:

```
def buscar_registro(self):
    
    registros = self.tabla.get_children()
    for element in registros:
        self.tabla.delete(element)

    query = f"SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '{self.Buscador.get()}%' " 
    self.run_query(query)
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tabla.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = row[3:7])
```

de esta manera, he logrado poder ordenar las busquedas a realizar y acomodarlas en mi vista de arbol principal.
Saludos, y gracias a todos los que colaboraron.

Comment: Procura ampliar un poco más tu respuesta explicando cómo funciona el código. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta, y no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.